# rewriterule redirect folder

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After all of the research, I have not been able to find the answer to this.

On the old website, html files were the format http://www.example.com/folder/file.html
I built the new site in wordpress with the url format http://www.example.com/folderfile/
I have had no problem stripping the .html off with a rewriterule, but how can I remove the / after folder? Is there any way to make

http://www.example.com/folder/file.html
redirect to
http://www.example.com/folderfile/
automatically?

Any advice is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works well:

```
 RewriteRule ^moreinfo/(.*)$ /moreinfo$1 [R=301]
 RewriteRule ^healthsolutions/(.*)$ /healthsolutions$1 [R=301]
```

Where /moreinfo/ and /healthsolutions/ are the folders

Answer (score 1):

Try out this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html$ ./$1$2/ [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/folderfile/ [L]
```

`http://www.example.com/folder/file.html` redirects to

`http://www.example.com/folderfile/`